# How to negate range inequality?

Tags: inequality

How would I negate an inequality like this:

$$1 < x < 2\quad?$$

My textbook says to flip the signs, but that seems to work only when the variable is on one side.

Comment: You would get $-1>-x>-2$

Comment: When you say *negate* the inequality, do you mean write down and simplify the condition that the inequality is *not satisfied*?  Or do you really mean to express the same inequality in terms of the opposites of the constants involved?

Answer (score 1):

$1<x<2$ means $1<x$ and $x<2$.

Your textbook is correct that the direction of the inequality should be reversed

when multiplying an [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Multiplication_and_division) by a negative number such as $-1$.

That would mean $-1>-x$ and $-x>-2$,

which means $-1>-x>-2$ (or, equivalently, $-2<-x<-1$).

---

Addendum in response to comment on OP:

If by "negate an inequality" you mean say it's not true

(rather than take the negative of each quantity, as I assumed above),

then $\lnot(1<x<2)$ means $\lnot(1<x \land x<2)$,

which means $\lnot(1<x)\lor \lnot(x<2)$, which means $x\le1$ or $x\ge2$.